# OctoberCMS project running on Nginx is returning 404 error in chrome

Tags: nginx, octobercms

I'm using nginx server for octobercms local development. Nginx is returning a 404 error for the url - localhost/backend in chrome. But with the same configuration, the site is working in firefox. Project folder is in the path /var/www/html/movies . Any pointers to the problem?

File - /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;

# SSL configuration
#
# listen 443 ssl default_server;
# listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
#
# Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
# See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
#
# Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
# See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
#
# Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
# Don't use them in a production server!
#
# include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

root /var/www/html;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name _;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

#   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
#   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#   # With php7.0-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;      
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;  
}


# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}
```

File - /etc/nginx/sites-available/movies

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name localhost localhost;
root /var/www/html/movies;
index index.php;

rewrite ^themes/.*/(layouts|pages|partials)/.*.htm /index.php break;
rewrite ^bootstrap/.* /index.php break;
rewrite ^config/.* /index.php break;
rewrite ^vendor/.* /index.php break;
rewrite ^storage/cms/.* /index.php break;
rewrite ^storage/logs/.* /index.php break;
rewrite ^storage/framework/.* /index.php break;
rewrite ^storage/temp/protected/.* /index.php break;
rewrite ^storage/app/uploads/protected/.* /index.php break;

location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}


location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you think we have an issue with project itself if its working in one browser and not working in another browser ? I mean both point at same. However, i would suggest you to check error log and see what you get there.

Comment: I was able to run the project using Apache server in multiple browsers.  The issue was seen only with nginx server. By error logs , do you mean nginx error logs?

Comment: yes .. nginx error logs

Comment: I would suggest changing the domain to something like `mywebsite.localhost` and updating your hosts file and see if the issue persists. Also, if you are only hosting one site off the server, make your movies configuration your `default_server`